# Tool to use Python-style indentation in latex?

Tags: editors

This may be asking too much, but I will ask it anyway.

I find this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
zlit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor 
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla 
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa 
qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}
        \label{fig:sample_figure}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}
        Something else
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

To be hideous, especially when captions get large, or there are multiple minipages in a figure, and you always end up not-balancing your `\begin`'s and `\end`s and spending years tracking down compiler errors.

I work normally with python, and find the indented-style to be much easier.  I would find something like:

```
\with{figure, centering}:
    \with{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}:
        \includegraphics[width=3.0in]{example-image-a}
        \with{caption}:
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
            esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
            occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
            deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        \label{fig:sample_figure}
    \with{minipage}:
        Something else
```

to be much easier to parse.  The question then: Is there some latex editor that lets you write your tex in this style and renders it as latex?

Comment: I doubt there is anything off the shelf, but it can't be hard for you to write a python preprocessor that runs over the file checking indent and writes out the real latex markup to pass to latex, if that's what you prefer. (The first syntax you show looks far clearer to me, but I accept that's just personal taste) it would be hard to do this within latex as white space at start of lines is discarded by default so not easily tested by any macros, but writing a preprocessor would only be a few lines of python or perl or sed or whatever.

Comment: or if you wrote the transform in lua you could use lualatex and the callback to process each input line

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder - you will get used to it soon enough. Also: it is probably much more practical to use the default notation in your own code, when you read code from others, share it with version control, use snippets from the internet, ask questions on TeX.SE and incorporate the answers in your code, etc.

Comment: While I accept that beauty is subjective - it is objectively true that when your environment is defined by `\begin{}`/`\end{}` blocks rather than indentation, it is not possible to check the level of nesting of a given line without scanning through the code for `\begin{}`/`\end{}` statements.  The python syntax makes it very easy to see what environment a given line of code belongs to.

Comment: a big difference between python and latex is that latex is a typesetter and whitespace is already significant for other reasons. as  `this and that` is not the same as `thisandthat`  you have exactly one word space between your two `minipage` as is clear in the top code. In the bottom code is the implied end environment supposed to imply a word space or not (and whichever the answer is, how do you get the other choice?)

Comment: Sorry I updated my code while you were making your comment, so I no longer know exactly what you were referring to.  But I would say: whitespace at the start of a line is considered to be for indentation purposes, and whitespace after any character is just whitespace.  An editor could easily highlight line-starting whitespace to make the distinction clear.

Comment: the comment still applies to your current question. In your first code you have `\end{minipage}<newline>\begin{minipage}` which is different from  `\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}` in the same way that `one two` is different from `onetwo`  are you suggesting that when implying an end of environment due to change of indent you _always_ add a word space after the environment?

Comment: Hah, no, that's definitely a trap.  So no, you don't implicitly add a word-space / newline you would have to do it explicitly by `\\ ` or `\n` or actually leaving a blank line or something.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like my dream typesetting language does not exist so it's a moot point.

Comment: As it stands this question feels too broad, having read the comments. (I originally thought it was just about formatting indents!) One could of course write either a preprocessor to output (La)TeX, a LaTeX package that completely changed the syntax or an independent format, but each of those is more than a few lines here, at least to do in it's entirety.